# multi auth using admin table inserting Credentials doesn't match

Tags: laravel, authentication

i am using multi guards one for admin and one for user
but when i log in and the information of ther user (email and password) is correct it returns Credentials doesn't match.
i don't know why although the info are correct

here is my config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

and here is my admin table

```
Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and here is my routes

```
Route::get('/admin/login', [AdminController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', [AdminController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login');
Route::get('/admin/logout', [AdminController::class, 'logout'])->name('admin.logout');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
```

and my AdminController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if(auth()->guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ])) {
        $user = auth()->user();

        return redirect()->intended(url('/admin/dashboard'));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withError('Credentials doesn\'t match.');
    }
}


});
```

and here is my login blade page

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 offset-3">
                <h1 class="text-center m-5">Admin login</h1>
                @if(\Session::has('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ \Session::get('error') }}</div>
                @endif
                <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Input email address">
                                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Input password">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you hashed your password for admin while inserting into database ?

Comment: no i havn't hased the password

Comment: i inserted into database manually

Comment: That's why. Well the `auth()->user()->attempt` method checks against the hashed password. You need to `\Hash::make('password-here') ` for admin while storing into the database

Comment: Admin must have no register page

Comment: still in database the password needs to be hashed using laravel facade. Check my proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Generate a hashed password from your tinker - open terminal on your project directory and type this line.

```
php artisan tinker
```

there you need to generate hashed password using

```
\Hash::make('your-password-here')
```

then copy the response and that's your hashed password.

you need that in database so the attempt method works, don't copy the double quotes.

[image]